Why is my Django app unable to find my URL pattern?
My Django project is run in Docker and I use Celery to handle queuing. When a user submits an audio file the system starts an asynchronous task(that transcribes the audio), continuously checks its progress, and updates the UI once the transcription is complete, with a download button. However I've been getting an error after the transcription completes but before the download button appears. The error indicates that it can't find the view that provides the completed transcript to the user. Here's my code.
views.py:
def initiate_transcription(request, session_id):
    file_name = request.session.get('uploaded_file_name')
    file_path = request.session.get('uploaded_file_path')

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not file_name or not file_path:
            return redirect(reverse('transcribeSubmit'))
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            if not file_name or not file_path:
                return redirect(reverse('transcribeSubmit'))
            
            audio_language = request.POST.get('audio_language')
            output_file_type = request.POST.get('output_file_type')
        
            if file_name and file_path:
                print(str("VIEW: "+session_id))
                task = transcribe_file_task.delay(file_path, audio_language, output_file_type, 'ai_transcribe_output', session_id)
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'task_id': task.id})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error': 'No file uploaded'})

    return render(request, 'transcribe/transcribe-complete-en.html')

def check_task_status(request, session_id, task_id):
    task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    if task_result.ready():
        transcribed_doc = TranscribedDocument.objects.get(id=session_id)
        return JsonResponse({
            'status': 'completed',
            'output_file_url': transcribed_doc.output_file.url
        })
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'pending'})

JS:
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const transcribeField = document.querySelector('.transcribe-output-lang-select')
    const errorDiv = document.querySelector('.error-transcribe-div');
    
    transcribeField.style.opacity = '0';
    setTimeout(function() {
        transcribeField.style.display = 'none';
        transcribingFileField.style.display = 'block';
        errorDiv.style.opacity = '0';
        errorDiv.style.display = 'none';

    }, 300); 
    setTimeout(function() {
        transcribingFileField.style.opacity = '1'

    }, 500); 
   
    const formData = new FormData(form);
 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                pollTaskStatus(response.task_id);
            } else {
                showError('An error occurred while initiating the transcription.');
            }
        } else {
            showError('An error occurred while uploading the file.');
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() {
        showError('An error occurred while uploading the file.');
    };

    xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
});

function pollTaskStatus(taskId) {
    const pollInterval = setInterval(() => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (response.status === 'completed') {
                    clearInterval(pollInterval);
                    showCompletedUI(response.output_file_url);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.open('GET', `/check_task_status/${taskId}/`, true);
        xhr.send();
    }, 5000); // Poll every 5 seconds
}

function showCompletedUI(outputFileUrl) {
    const transcribingText = document.querySelector('.transcribing-text');
    transcribingText.textContent = 'Transcript Completed';

    const downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download-btn');
    downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        window.location.href = outputFileUrl;
        this.innerHTML = 'Transcript downloaded!';
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.innerHTML = 'Click to download';
        }, 3000);
    });
}

function showError(message) {
    const errorDiv = document.querySelector('.error-transcribe-div');
    errorDiv.textContent = message;
    errorDiv.style.opacity = '1';
    errorDiv.style.display = 'block';
    
    const transcribingFileField = document.querySelector('.transcribing-file-field');
    transcribingFileField.style.opacity = '0';
    transcribingFileField.style.display = 'none';
}


function showTranscriptionComplete(fileUrl) {
    // Update UI to show transcription is complete
    console.log('success')
    const transcribingText = document.querySelector('.transcribing-text');
    transcribingText.textContent = 'Transcript Completed';
    const orderComplete = document.querySelector('.order-complete-data');
    orderComplete.style.opacity = '0';
    transcriptComplete = document.querySelector('.transcript-complete');
    const transcriptSVG = document.querySelector('.transcript-svg');

    setTimeout(function() {
        orderComplete.style.display = 'none';
        transcriptComplete.style.opacity = '1';
        transcriptComplete.style.display = 'block';
        transcribeLoader.style.opacity = '0';
        transcribeLoader.style.display = 'none';
        transcriptSVG.style.opacity = '1';
        transcriptSVG.style.display = 'block';
    }, 300); 

    let blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')});
    let fileName = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1];
    console.log(fileName);
    
    // Set up download button
    const downloadBtn = document.querySelector('.download-btn');

    downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        download(blob, fileName);
        this.innerHTML = 'Transcript downloaded！';
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.innerHTML = 'Click to download';
        }, 3000);
    }
    )};

urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.transcribeSubmit, name="transcribeSubmit"),
    path("init-transcription/<str:session_id>/", views.initiate_transcription, name="initiate_transcription"),
    path("check_task_status/<str:task_id>/", views.check_task_status, name="check_task_status"),
]

Here's the error log:
web-1     | Not Found: /check_task_status/02760416-c2fb-4526-b0d0-d5cdafabf8cf/


Well, check_task_status view expects two positional parameters, yet your url is just passing one xhr.open('GET', ``/check_task_status/${taskId}/``, true); not comlpetely sure if that is the source of your problem tho.
